# where clause in nested select statement based on group by parameters

Tags: sqlite

I would like to form an sql query something like below but can not figure out how to make it work:

```
SELECT col_1 AS a,
       col_2 AS b,
       (SELECT sum(col_3)
        FROM table2
        WHERE col_1 = a
          AND col_2 = b) AS c
FROM table1
GROUP BY col_1, col_2;
```

Comment: What do you mean by "can not figure out how to to make it work"? What is not working, what are you expecting to happen. Include any errors your are receiving.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Column aliases are not available in a subquery.

You have to refer to the columns directly:

```
SELECT col_1 AS a,
       col_2 AS b,
       (SELECT sum(col_3)
        FROM table2
        WHERE col_1 = table1.col_1
          AND col_2 = table1.col_2) AS c
FROM table1
GROUP BY col_1, col_2;
```